# A Boolean is required

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I want to change the background color of Object in Crystal report according to some Condition which is (e.g)

```
  if (({DataTableCable.ColumnChange} and 4) = 4) then
  crGreen
```

DataTableCable.ColumnChange is a field Contains a number , i want to make a bitwise and with 4 , if the result is 4 then change the background of Object 
but i receive the following error
"A Boolean is required"
how should make a bitwise and in crystal report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I'm reading your post correctly, you are trying to perform a *bitwise* comparison against your value (`{DataTableCable.ColumnChange}`) in the Crystal Reports code.

Looking around online, I can't seem to see anything that indicates that crystal can perform that kind of comparison. One alternative is to perform that calculation in your *.Net* code, and store it against a property/column of your datasource object - that way you can simply check if the property is true/false.

**Update**

Another option, perhaps, is to perform manual arithmetic to calculate this. [Nopadol](http://nopadolsiri.wordpress.com/2008/12/30/custom-functions-of-bitwise-in-crystal-reports-9/) (Link provided by OP) seems to have good examples of how to do this (I've reproduced the code below for posterity). The [No Stress Tech Guide to Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EBYLEisY7bQC&lpg=SA9-PA10&ots=52Rgv2L_xt&dq=crystal%20open%20Formula%20editor&pg=SA9-PA1#v=onepage&q&f=false) (Lesson 9) seems to cover the use of the Formula Editor which should help get you started.

```
Function Name: ToBin
Function (NumberVar n)
(
    Local StringVar b;
    Local NumberVar d;
    b := "";
    d := n;
    Do
    (
        b := CStr(Truncate(d Mod 2),0) & b;
        d := Truncate(d / 2);
    )
    While (d > 1);
    CStr(Truncate(d),0) & b;
)

Function Name: ToNum
Function (StringVar b)
(
    Local NumberVar lng := length(b);
    Local NumberVar n := 0;
    Local NumberVar i;
    For i := lng To 1 Step -1 Do
    (
        n := n + ((2 ^ (lng – i)) * Truncate(ToNumber(Mid(b,i,1))))
    );
    n;
)

Function Name: BitAnd
Function (NumberVar n1, NumberVar n2)
(
    Local StringVar b1 := ToBin(n1);
    Local StringVar b2 := ToBin(n2);
    Local NumberVar l1 := length(b1);
    Local NumberVar l2 := length(b2);
    Local NumberVar lng := IIF(l1 > l2, l1, l2);
    Local StringVar x;
    Local StringVar y;
    Local StringVar z := "";
    Local NumberVar i;
    For i := lng To 1 Step -1 Do
    (
        x := "0";
        If (l1 >= i) Then
            x := Mid(b1, (l1-i)+1, 1);
        y := "0";
        If (l2 >= i) Then
            y := Mid(b2, (l2-i)+1, 1);
        z := z & IIF(x=y And x="1","1","0");
    );
    ToNum(z);
)

Function Name: BitXOr
Function (NumberVar n1, NumberVar n2)
(
    n1 + n2 – (BitAnd(n1, n2) * 2)
)

Function Name: BitOr
Function (NumberVar n1, NumberVar n2)
(
    n1 + n2 – BitAnd(n1, n2)
)

Example

BitAnd(1, 5)  // = 1
BitXOr(1, 5)  // = 4
BitOr(1, 5)  // = 5
```

Comment: that ColumnChange field contains a value with i can understand which one of my columns had a difference with older version . i have about 15 columns in a report. so you mean i have to have 14 other value in .Net Code to see if the corresponding Column has Changed? Sorry for english

Comment: If you needed to perform this kind of operation on all 15 columns, then yeah I suppose that is what I'm saying. What are you passing into the Crystal Datasource? Is it a datatable, or a list of a class? If it's a class list, you could possibly write a function to process a given value? Honestly, I don't use Crystal, I was just attempting to clarify your requirement and provide some info based on online searches.

Comment: I found this http://nopadolsiri.wordpress.com/2008/12/30/custom-functions-of-bitwise-in-crystal-reports-9/ but i don't know how to create a new Forumla Editor

Comment: This might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227603(v=vs.80).aspx  EDIT: Or maybe not. Seems different to what they say in your link.

Comment: Or try this eBook. Lesson 9 seems to cover it. http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=EBYLEisY7bQC&lpg=SA9-PA10&ots=52Rgv2L_xt&dq=crystal%20open%20Formula%20editor&pg=SA9-PA1#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: I have a error on To Num,don't you? "The ) is missing"

Comment: I'm not attempting to run the code. I've merely copied it from the site so that the answer is complete even if the source site is removed. The Brackets seem to be find on the ToNum - there aren't any orphan brackets. If it's wrong let me know what you changed and I'll amend the sample.

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't compile in C# or VB.NET at all. However, maybe you want something like this:

```
if (DataTableCable.ColumnChange == 4) 
{
    // change to green
}
```

Comment: i want to check if the logical and of ColumnChange  with 4 is 4 then do the rest,ColumnChange  could be any value

Comment: @nnmmss it appears that you are using a single `=` instead of `==` you are attempting to assign the variable as `4` instead of comparing it against `4`

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand your requirement(language barrier). Maybe it helps if you show a compiling snippet that clarifies the problem.

Comment: @nnmmss you are looking for `&` instead of `and`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I think the problem is that this is *Crystal* code, not .Net, and the OP is looking to perform a bitwise comparison on the value provided in `{DataTableCable.ColumnChange}`

Answer (score 2):

> i want to check if the logical and of ColumnChange with 4 is 4 then do the rest

so you need to use `&` < logical and, and use `==` (comparision) instead of `=` (assignment)

```
if ((DataTableCable.ColumnChange & 4)== 4) 
{
    // change to green
}
```

Comment: in crystal report it doesn't accept ==, it says "A Number, currency amount, date, time, or string is required "